# Change first character on a line with upper case perl

Tags: regex, perl

This is a simple question I guess, but I was trying to change just the first lower case letter of a line from a .txt file to an upper case, using the following

```
$_ =~ s/^[a-z]/\U/;
```

What happens, when I execute it, is that instead of changing the lower case to upper case the lower case at the beginning of the line is substituted with the most significant bit on the line. For example, the line `nAkld987aBALPaapofikU88` instead of being substituted with `NAkld987` becomes `Akld987...`

Comment: `$_ =~ s/.../.../;` is the same as `s/.../.../;`.

Comment: Note that your regex will find the first character of the line if it is lower case, not the first lower case character on the line.

Comment: i forget about these symbols in regexs, good rich perl, yeah

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to capture the `first character` in a capturing group, and use `back reference` to convert it to `uppercase` using `\u`.

Try using this: -

```
$_ =~ s/^([a-z])/\u$1/;
```

Comment: Why launch into a regex when Perl has a ucfirst function?

Comment: @DaveCross.. Yeah you are right. And OP has got that answer from the other answer here. I just quoted what he did wrong in his Regex. Frankly speaking, I didn't knew about `that function` in Perl. (Just new to Perl). :)

Comment: Is this possible to do this in Notepad++ without install any addons?

Comment: the advantage of this over `ucfirst` is that you can do this (more) easily from the command line directly, e.g. `| perl -pe 's{(.)}{\u$1}g'`

Comment: Does not work with UTF-8 or accented, Latin-1 characters.

Answer (score 31):

You could/should use `ucfirst`.  I say should as it's much more obvious to a maintainer that your intent is to uppercase the first letter of the string.  I love a regex, but in this case I feel it's not the correct approach.

```
my $str = "test";
print ucfirst($str);
```

Comment: ucfirst() works on utf-8, too, while the accepted answer does not.  print(ucfirst("николай")); # output: "Николай"

Answer (score 15):

You can just use the `ucfirst` function.

If you want to use regex you can do:

```
$_ =~ s/^([a-z])/\u$1/;
```

or

```
$_ =~ s/^([a-z])/\U$1\E/;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone The reason I want to use regexes is because I will need them and so I am practicing now.

Answer (score 0):

Being less proficient with regular expressions, I accomplished this with `map` (which is basically `foreach`, except it both iterates a list and returns the manipulated list):

```
$string = join " ", map { ucfirst } split " ", $string;
```